# Visual Studio Installer: Move files from custom folder to TargetDir depends on the Registry Search value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I am creating a visual studio installer 2010 project. I have a custom folder which contain some files that needs to be installed only if the condition "search target machine by registry" returns a specific value. Below are the screenshots of the process I am following. But the condition seems to be not working.

Registry search screenshot:

[image]

File system editor custom folder properties:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough in the screen shot to show exactly where you are searching.

However, you seem to have the condition on the folder, which doesn't work. It needs to be on all the files. Internally, the condition is a condition on the component being installed, not on the folder, in spite of the Visual Studio IDE apparently allowing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, due to the complexity in the conditions to check on the files i have created a custom action to move the files to the installation directory.

Comment: But I am having another issue in creating the shortcut for the application. The shortcut which was created is not having the Target location. So, when I click on the shortcut created it is kicking off the installer process and not the actual installed application. The only difference from the online articles with respect to my implementation is I am directly creating the shortcut for the exe file that is there in my Application folder( it is not primary output).

Comment: Shortcuts generated by Visual Studio setups using the IDE are advertised shortcuts that don't directly refer to the executable. That is normal. They have a resilience capability, which means that if files are deleted after they were installed they will be restored by getting them from the original MSI file. That's almost certainly the issue.